# clone span into textfield from sum of fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How do I take the result from **"#sum"** and have it auto duplicated in a textfield so that when I submit a form, the value gets sent also?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(":text").each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function() {
                calculateSum();
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
    var sum=0;
    $(":text").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0 {
            sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
   $("#myTextField").val(sum.toFixed(0)); //adding to text field
}
</script>
```

Is there a quick fix to this?

This is where the actual value updates on the HTML page.

```
<span id="sum">0</span>
```

It is not adding right. If I type in 500 in one of the fields it now takes the first number and repeats, so if I type 500 it outputs as 555

any help?

Comment: can you just post HTML as well?

Comment: You are re-declaring the variable `sum` each time that function is called, which is every `keyup`, and your `calculateSum` function is iterating over each textbox every time a key is pressed in ANY textbox, is this what you want?

Comment: `<form name="form1" method="post" action="input.php">
<input name="qty1" type="text"  size="8"  />
<input name="qty2" type="text"  size="8"  />
<input name="qty3" type="text"  size="8"  />
<input name="qty4" type="text"  size="8"  />
<input name="total_qty" type="text"  id="total_qty" />

</form>`

Comment: Yes, whenever the number is changed in  the textbox it should calculate and change. I just cant get that number to post in a txtfield correctly

Comment: You are saying your function is doing everything right you just need the sum which is in `<span id="sum">` to be printed in some text field to appear on the next page... is that what you need ?

Comment: no i need it to appear on the same page so when i submit it gets passed through the form

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is is that ":text" is selecting myTextField. So your final value is being added back in.
5 = 5; 50 + 5 = 55; 500 + 55 = 555; You can try using the not selector.

$(":text:not('#myTextField')")

http://jsfiddle.net/RhRbR/

```
$(":text:not(#myTextField)").each(function() {
  if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum+=parseFloat(this.value);
  }
})
```

The fiddle can show you the way.